# How to unlock WP7 device in order to deploy the app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment, device

i researched a lot to unlock my nokia lumia windows 7 device in order to deploy my app but didn't find any satisfying answer or procedure. I'm a student and wanted to test my final thesis app on my device but when i go for the device unlock procedure i have to pay for it for Microsoft's developer account in order to test the app. Please guide me is there any other way to test the app on my device ?

Comment: No. You have to register for a developer account and pay $99 a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/help/jj206719(v=vs.105).aspx

> Individual or Student: Select Individual if you’re an individual developer. Select Student if you’re a student with a verified DreamSpark account. You can get a new DreamSpark account during registration. At this point, you’ll be required to provide proof of your student status. **There’s no annual membership fee for if you purchase the subscription using DreamSpark**. You’ll receive a verification email from Dev Center to validate your email account.

If your university is part of the Microsoft Dreamspark Program, you are lucky in this case :)